# How can I show either text or a link in a table using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a project which will generate a presigned URL for an object stored in an S3 bucket. I have a method that takes in the bucket name and path name and returns the presigned URL if successful or returns a concatenation of the bucket and path if an exception occurs. What I would like to do is display a direct download link if the URL is returned or display text (*not* a link) with the concatenated bucket/path if URL generation was not successful. I thought I could do something like the following:

View:

```
 <div id="dataView">
     <table>
         <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>URL</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: data>
              <tr>
                  <!-- ko if: urlIsValid -->
                      <td>
                          <a data-bind="attr: {href: location}" target="_blank">
                              Download
                          </a>
                      </td>
                  <!-- /ko -->
                  <!-- ko ifnot: urlIsValid -->
                      <td data-bind="text: location"></td>
                  <!-- /ko -->
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
"use strict"

P.when('knockout', 'ready').register('data_model',
     function(ko) {

    var GetDataModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.urlIsValid = ko.observable();
        self.data = ko.observableArray();
        self.example = [ "https://www.example.com", "bucketName/pathName" ]

        function isValidURL(urlToCheck) {
            return urlToCheck.lastIndexOf("http", 0) === 0;
        }

        function pushData() {
            for (var i = 0; i < example.length; ++i) {
                self.urlIsValid = isValidURL(self.example[i]);
                self.data.push ( {
                    location : self.example[i];
                } );
            }
        }
    }

    var dataModel = GetDataModel();
    ko.applyBindings(dataModel, document.getElementById('dataView'));
});
```

There is additional logic that kicks off the `pushData` function when a button on the page is clicked. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to make the link/text display work. I should mention that if I remove the `<!-- ko if -->` and `<!-- ko ifnot -->` statements and just create a link no matter the circumstances, it works as expected. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: You're overwriting your observable and breaking the data-bind. `self.urlIsValid = isValidURL(self.example[i]);` should be a function assignment like `self.urlIsValid(isValidURL(self.example[i]));`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but it still isn't working. When I take out the ko if/ifnot statements (no changes to JS) and have it create a link no matter what, it runs perfectly fine, but as soon as I put the ko if/ifnot statements back in, it doesn't work. I put some alerts in my JS and found that when the ko if/ifnot statements are included, it will execute an alert before pushing the data to the array but it won't execute an alert placed after. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say the link doesn't work do you mean it's not being displayed at all or that it shows but doesn't navigate correctly?

Comment: It doesn't display at all (actually nothing in the table displays -- it seems to hang for some reason because nothing I put after `self.data.push` gets executed either).

Comment: If you comment out the urlIsValid setter in pushData and set urlIsValid to true manually when it is defined (`self.urlIsValid = ko.observable(true);`) does the link display?

Comment: No, nothing displays and nothing put after `self.data.push` executes either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the binding context where isValidURL is nested within `foreach:data` I think you probably want isValidURL to be a property on each member of the data array rather than a property on the root view-model. It also doesn't need to be observable unless you'll be updating those links at run-time.

```js
var GetDataModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray();
  self.example = [ "https://www.example.com", "bucketName/pathName" ];

  function isValidURL(urlToCheck) {
    return urlToCheck.lastIndexOf("http", 0) === 0;
  }

  function pushData() {
    for (var i = 0; i < self.example.length; ++i) {
      //self.urlIsValid = isValidURL(self.example[i]);
      self.data.push ( {
        location : self.example[i],
        urlIsValid: isValidURL(self.example[i])
      });
    }
  }
  
  setTimeout(pushData, 500);
}

var dataModel = GetDataModel();
ko.applyBindings(dataModel, document.getElementById('dataView'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dataView">
     <table>
         <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>URL</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
              <tr>
              <td><span data-bind="text: urlIsValid"></span></td>
                  <!-- ko if: urlIsValid -->
                      <td>
                          <a data-bind="attr: {href: location}" target="_blank">
                              Download
                          </a>
                      </td>
                  <!-- /ko -->
                  <!-- ko ifnot: urlIsValid -->
                      <td data-bind="text: location"></td>
                  <!-- /ko -->
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
 </div>
```